# Apply condition between two fields in drupal 7 by using JQuery

Tags: entities, javascript

This is updated JQuery code I have created condition between two fields in drupal 7 i.e. If we select item from first field then as per there selected item, some items of second field is going to hidden. But problem is that : If first I select item from second select field & after that I have select same item in first field then in this condition my created condition is wrong. Please Help to solve this. Thanks

Please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/19/)

**Below is my my updated JQuery code**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
abc();
$("#edit-main-field-i-am-field-und").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var optionText = $(this).find('option[value='+value+']').val();

    $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').show();

       if(optionText=="sbf" || optionText=="smf" )
       {

           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).val()=="sbf" || $(this).val()=="smf")

                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }
      else
       {

           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).val()=="sdm" || $(this).val()=="sbm")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }

    });
});

function abc()
{

   var value = $('#edit-main-field-i-am-field-und').val();



if(value=="sbf" || value=="smf" )
       {

           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).val()=="sbf" || $(this).val()=="smf")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }
      else
       {

           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).val()=="sdm" || $(this).val()=="sbm")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and got a quick solution i.e. reset second select box every time first is changed.

look how I have implemented the same:

```
$(function(){
$("#edit-main-field-i-am-field-und").change(function() {

    $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').val("_none"); // added to reset second select box on chanage of first one

       var value = $(this).val(); 
       var optionText = $(this).find('option[value='+value+']').text();
    $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').show();
       if(optionText=="A" || optionText=="C" )
       {
         //alert("12345");
           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).text()=="A" || $(this).text()=="C")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }
      else
       {
           //alert("98765");
           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).text()=="B" || $(this).text()=="D")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }
    $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und option:visible:eq(1)').prop('selected',true);
   // alert($('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').val());
    });
});
```

I have just added `$('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').val("_none");` in .change function.

Comment: :( it's working on Demo if I make change but I try on my localhost.. It's not working @Ashish

Comment: I have tried it in jsfiddle and its working for me, what issue you are getting?

Comment: try code with slight change 
$('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').val("");

Comment: It's working now... no need to change any thing.. Thanks alot @Ashish

Comment: I have 1 query what it mean to put this "$('#edit-profile-main-field-look-for-field-und option:visible:eq(1)').prop('selected',true);".. If I remove this.. no issue with jquery.. @Ashish

Comment: I think it was intended to do the same but wrongly placed and coded, I have done same at right place with right code. :)

Comment: Now its working correctly.. I make some changes...

Comment: Please have a look in this link... I have some query related my above question "http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/132202/how-to-add-js-file-in-drupal-7"